# How to check if the current time falls in a particular range of time?

Tags: c#, time, range

I want to create a trigger.
I give two inputs.
a)Start Time
b)End time.

I want to continuously check if the current time falls between start time and end time. And toggle the value of a global variable between 0(not in range) and 1(in range).

But I need to check it every sec.

what I am doing now is following

```
while (true)
{
    now_hrs = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Hour);
    now_min = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Minute);

    if (now_hrs >= start_hrs && now_hrs <= end_hrs)
    {
        if (now_hrs == start_hrs && now_min < start_min)
        {

        }
        else if (now_hrs == end_hrs && now_min > end_min)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            alert_trigger = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get nothing and the program hangs.

Is there any other way to check whether the current time falls in the range

or

change the value of the alert_trigger to 1 between start and end time and 0 otherwise..

Comment: Can you provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: I can tell you right away that some of those semi colons after your `if` statements are not right.

Comment: sure example:
start_hrs=10
end_hrs=10
start_min=15
end_min=30.

so between 10:15 and 10:30, value of alert_trigger= 1
else,
alert_trigger=0

Comment: the semicolons are just to do nothing and just run the next iteration

Comment: please accept answer by click on tick.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `start` and `end` are of type `DateTime`:

```
while(true)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    alert_trigger = (now > start && now < end) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't call `DateTime.Now` twice. Doesn't matter here, but still.

Comment: @Gustav you are right, the value should be cached. I just wanted a quick proof of concept, but I modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Work with `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`:

```
var start = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0); // your start time
var end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);   // your end time

while(true)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    if (now <= end && now >= start)
    {
        alert_trigger = 1
    }
}
```

Also, think about another solution but active waiting in a `while` loop. Maybe subscribing to a `Tick`-event of a `Timer`.

Comment: it doesn't matter whether you use `var` or `TimeSpan`. `var` results in `TimeSpan` after compilation. It is called implicit typed variable, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx im just using it all the time since it is faster to code and you can see that it is a TimeSpan if you look at the right side of the statements.. :) It is really just a matter of style or if you like it this way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

use from `DateTime.compare`

```
private void compareTime(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
    if(DateTime.compare(cur, start)>0 && DateTime.compare(cur, end)<0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to compare to `DateTimes`, he want to know whether the DayTIme of a DateTime is in a certain range of time... (hrs, mins, secs..)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the CompareTo method:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(15);
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(30);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

while(true)
{
    alert_trigger = (now.CompareTo(start) >= 0 && now.CompareTo(end) <= 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

If start and end time should be excluded, you can reduce to:

```
while(true)
{
    alert_trigger = (now.CompareTo(start) + now.CompareTo(end) = 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```